# Why did the codeigniter 3 site stop working when moved to a new hosting company?

Tags: php, hosting, codeigniter-3

I'm moving an old Codeigniter 3 site to a new hosting company and I've run into a problem.

I believe the path info and the database are configured correctly.  But, when I visit the url, a local dialog box prompts me to save a file.  The saved file is given an 8 random character name and it seems contain the text of the index.php file.

Any ideas what might be causing this behavior or how I can fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Check the log files for errors.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Thanks for your suggestion!  It turned out to be something in the .htaccess file from the prior hosting company.  Once that was removed everything started working.  Thanks again